# Given a Pattern, find the fractal

Tags: group-theory, fractals

Is it possible, given a *pattern* or *image,* to calculate the equation of the fractal for that given pattern?

For example, many plants express definite fractal patterns in their growth. Is there a formula or set of processes that give the fractal equation of their growth?

Comment: The Wikipedia link provided by Jim, with respect to "L-systems" lists, as an ***open problem***: "Given a structure, find an L-system that can produce that structure." Nice question, though! The same link provided by Jim (L-systems), has as a book reference, a link to a pdf book that you might be interested in: Przemyslaw Prusinkiewicz, Aristid Lindenmayer - *The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants*, http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop, though there are also many additional links and resources that may be of interest, which you can access directly from the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: what do you mean by "the equation of the fractal"? Do you have an example of a fractal together with its equation?

Comment: The L-system problems as mentioned by @amWhy and @Jim Belk, are what I'd like to do with plants. Thank you gentlemen, I didn't know it was an open problem, explained why I couldn't get an answer out of Google! In addition, I'd like to know if there is a way to take the images generated in [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32062/mandelbrot-fractal-how-is-it-possible/32067#32067) answer and determine that this is a Mandelbrot fractal, for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As requested, I'm posting my comment as an answer here:

The Wikipedia link provided by Jim, with respect to "L-systems" lists, as an ***open problem***:

> "Given a structure, find an L-system that can produce that structure."

It is a great question, though! The same link provided by Jim (on L-systems), lists a book reference, including a link to the book in pdf format that you might be interested in: Przemyslaw Prusinkiewicz, Aristid Lindenmayer - [***Algorithmic Beauty of Plants***](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop)  (for URL: algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop). There you can download any/all of the following pdfs:

```
Chapter 1 - Graphical modeling using L-systems (2Mb; LQ, 1Mb)
Chapter 2 - Modeling of trees (4Mb; LQ, 300kb)
Chapter 3 - Developmental models of herbaceous plants (1.7Mb; LQ, 500kb)
Chapter 4 - Phyllotaxis (2.5Mb; LQ, 500kb)
Chapter 5 - Models of plant organs (1.2Mb; LQ, 300kb)
Chapter 6 - Animation of plant development (650kb; LQ, 160kb)
Chapter 7 - Modeling of cellular layers (3.7Mb; LQ, 800kb)
Chapter 8 - Fractal properties of plants (1.2Mb; LQ, 300kb)
```

There are also many *additional links* and resources that may be of interest, which you can access directly from the Wikipedia entry.

Comment: Very nice reference, I have always wanted to go back and study fractals and especially drawing these graphics more. +1

Answer (score 12):

There are two common ways to describe the shapes of simple fractals:

- You can specify a generating set of self-similarities for the fractal.  These self-similarities form an [iterated function system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function_system), which can be used to reconstruct the original fractal.  This is the method used to construct the [Barnsley fern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnsley_fern):

[image: Barnsley fern]

- You can specify a [Lindenmayer system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system) (or L-system) for the fractal.  Wikipedia gives the following examples of "weeds" constructed using an L-system:

[image]

(Note: Both pictures are from Wikipedia.)

Answer (score 8):

For images, there is an automatic method, [fractal compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_compression).