# Fractals reference

Tags: reference-request, fractals

I want to present an elementary lecture about Fractals in the Nature. So, I am searching open or online references with good pictures like the following one:

[image] [image]

I prepared a good program that makes the fractals and the participants don't  know much the analysis patterns behind this concept, so I am going to introduce Fractals in the Nature just by doing some graphical figures or setting formulas and etc. I will be so pleased if I know your suggestions.Thanks for the time  you will give me.

Comment: Do you need something better than what [Google](http://goo.gl/Uimzx) returns?

Comment: @Babak S. Pretty picture. Maybe [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/323455/55235) interests you.

Comment: @Babak S.:The Fractal Geometry of Nature 1982(Benoit B. Mandelbrot) and Fractal concepts in surface growth 1995(  Barabasi A.-L., Stanley H.E.)

Comment: @Babak S.:this site is nice http://fractalfoundation.org

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I highly recommend the book that Maisam referenced in the comments below your question: Mendelbrot's [*The Fractal Geometry of Nature*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0716711869). It is widely acclaimed, and likely available at a library, public and/or academic.

You might be interested in some of the links in this "[given the pattern, find the fractal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46585/given-a-pattern-find-the-fractal/46747#46747)" math.SE post: In particular, you might want to check out the link to [The Algorithmic Beauty of Plants](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/#abop), which is a "book" whose chapters are available on-site for downloading in pdf form.

Of particular interest might be the chapter entitled: [Modeling of Trees](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/abop/abop-ch2.pdf), and [Fractal Properties of Plants](http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/abop/abop-ch8.pdf).

For a vast array of examples of fractals, and a categorization of some major types, see the commercial website [Fractal Science Kit](http://www.fractalsciencekit.com/gallery/gallery.htm) (free for the browsing!)

Also, a link of interest might be the [Yale Website](http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/Mandelset/welcome.html) for a class in Fractals. [This page on "forgeries"](http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/Panorama/Art/Forgeries/Forgeries.html) might be of particular interest. E.g.:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Perhaps Mandelbrot knew more than we realized. My favorite application so far is that the antenna inside cell phones use fractals and that these have been proven to give optimal reception.

Answer (score 2):

As I surfed in the net I found some useful links and books
;

1.The Fractal Geometry of Nature 1982(Benoit B. Mandelbrot) and Fractal concepts in surface growth 1995( Barabasi A.-L., Stanley H.E.)

2.http://fractalfoundation.org/

Answer (score 2):

Maybe photos [here](https://en-maktoob.news.yahoo.com/photos/mind-bending-mosque-photography-slideshow/?format=embed#mediaphotosbobaspotlightgallery=%2Flightbox%2Fmind-bending-mosque-photography-slideshow%2F) be useful. There are 18 photos there.

Answer (score 1):

Try coastlines? I've read somewhere fractal dimension of english coastline is close to that of koch's snowflake..

Answer (score 1):

Since they're used to define fractal dimension, it might be good to show how logarithms give you a scale-based measuring system, based on ratios of distances instead of absolute positions - decibels, 12TET, a map of the city where your house is all big, plotting a number line starting with a nice distance between 1 and 2 and shortening it small enough to not notice much as you look at the end of the page and are thinking about how you're going to fit 100 in there.